# PWA env MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL change to local virtual host problem

Tags: configuration, setup, pwa-studio

Passed a lot of solutions but didn't get the success

The task if the replace the default local virtual host pwa02.wsl wher M2 installed

- M2 vesion: 2.4.5 (working well)
- Venia varsion: 13.2.0

Istalled via yarn

MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL=https://master-7rqtwti-c5v7sxvquxwl4.eu-4.magentosite.cloud/
DEV_SERVER_HOST=pwa02.wsl
DEV_SERVER_PORT=10000

yarn buildpack create-custom-origin packages/venia-concept

Working well

Backend URL replecements to pwa02.wsl

create-custom-origin rebuilt as URL changed.

Started on http://pwa02.wsl:10000/ well

1. Home works
2. Category works, disable/enable category tested
3. PDP preloading: I saw layout frameworks (https://imgur.com/ITvWJxm)
4. PDP failed: Looks like something went wrong. Sorry about that  (https://imgur.com/AmsEksX)